# How to check whether INSERT INTO id already exist in Database (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

How do I check whether the ID which I am planning to insert to my table already exist? And if so how do I repeat the process

```
$itemID = rand(1,99);
$itemName = $_POST['insert_item_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO items (id, name) VALUES('$itemID', '$itemName')";
```

Comment: Why not set your id column to AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want is to run a select first to check - but that might not be the best solution. The common approach is to use a column such as `auto_increment` which means you just insert a `null` into the table for that column and the database will increment by one automatically.

Eg, with an [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column, all you need to do is insert like this:

```
insert into items (id, name) values (null, 'SomeName');
```

This will ensure that the column is unique and will never end up with multiple records for the same id.

You can also try something like [replace into](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) which will replace the row if it is there already with that ID.

```
replace into items(id, name) values (3,'SomeName');
```

This will insert a row into the table if there isn't one, or replace what is there with the new data in your query - but you need to ensure that the column `id` is set to unique when creating the table.

Answer (score -1):

```
$aSql  = mysql_query("select count(*) from table where id = '$itemID'");
$iCnt = mysql_fetch_array($aSql);
if($iCnt > 0)
{
   echo "Id already exists";
}
else
{
  echo "insett new id";
}
```

Comment: What if two instances of the script run this at the same time?